# How to repeat all lines containing tagged segments, so that only one segment appears tagged on each line in BASH?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file marked with segments, identified with pairs of `{` and `}`:

```
{One day}, {the cat said to the owl}, "{Owl}, {would you like to climb the mountain}?"
{The owl replied}, "{Yes}, {I would}."
{So the cat and owl climbed the mountain}.
{The next day}, {they went to the ocean}.
```

I need to duplicate all of the lines, such that there is only one tagged segment per line. A line with four tagged segments would be duplicated four times, with each line showing only one of the segments marked. The result would look like this:

```
{One day}, the cat said to the owl, "Owl, would you like to climb the mountain?"
One day, {the cat said to the owl}, "Owl, would you like to climb the mountain?"
One day, the cat said to the owl, "{Owl}, would you like to climb the mountain?"
One day, the cat said to the owl, "Owl, {would you like to climb the mountain}?"
{The owl replied}, "Yes, I would."
The owl replied, "{Yes}, I would."
The owl replied, "Yes, {I would}."
{So the cat and owl climbed the mountain}.
{The next day}, they went to the ocean.
The next day, {they went to the ocean}.
```

- The braces are never nested.
- The braces are never split across lines.
- If it is more convenient, I could replace `{` and `}` with any other symbols.

How to repeat all lines containing tagged segments, so that only one segment appears tagged on each line in `sed` or another BASH tool?

Comment: gotta be BASH? probably awk is the way to go, but it's complicated to not use a scripting langauge like python.

Comment: Yeah, you want to use perl, python, or php -- a language that lets you get a list of all the matches to a regular expression and loop over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/{/!d;s/{[^}]*}/\n&\n/;h;s/[{}]//g;s/\n/{/;s/\n/}/;G;P;s/[^\n]*\n//;s/\n{//;s/}\n//;ba' file
```

Only print lines which contain curly braces (if you want to print these lines replace the `d` by `b`). Surround the first set of curly braces by a unique marker (newlines are a good choice). Copy the line, remove all curly braces and replace the first marker by an opening curly brace and the second marker by a closing curly brace. Append the copied line. Print the first amended line. Remove the first line and its newline. Remove the first set of curly braces and repeat.

A slightly shorter version along the same lines:

```
sed ':a;/{/!d;h;s/{[^}]*}/\n&\n/;s/[{}]//g;s/\n/{/;s/\n/}/p;z;x;s/{//;s/}//;ba' file
```

Comment: N.B. If you want to print lines without braces, you will need to place a condition for braceless lines following the removal of the first set of braces i.e. `....s/}//;/{/!d;ba`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this `awk`,

One liner:

```
awk -F, '{ line=$0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ $0=line; for( j=1; j<=NF; j++){ if( i != j ){gsub(/{|}/,"",$j);}}print $0;}}' OFS=, your_file.txt
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f                                                                                                                         

BEGIN {
        FS=",";
        OFS=",";
}
{
        line=$0;
        for( i=1; i<=NF; i++){
                $0=line;
                for( j=1; j<=NF; j++){
                        if( i != j){
                                gsub(/{/,"",$j);
                                gsub(/}/,"",$j);
                        }
                }
                print $0;
        } 

}
```

**Test:**

```
sat:~# awk -f sample.awk file.txt
{One day}, the cat said to the owl, "Owl, would you like to climb the mountain?"
One day, {the cat said to the owl}, "Owl, would you like to climb the mountain?"
One day, the cat said to the owl, "{Owl}, would you like to climb the mountain?"
One day, the cat said to the owl, "Owl, {would you like to climb the mountain}?"
{The owl replied}, "Yes, I would."
The owl replied, "{Yes}, I would."
The owl replied, "Yes, {I would}."
{So the cat and owl climbed the mountain}.
{The next day}, they went to the ocean.
The next day, {they went to the ocean}.
```

Comment: `gsub(/{|}/,"",$j)` can be used to replace two gsub() commands. Oh, just find out, jaypal used this way already.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/{|}/,"",$0);sub(/[^".?]+/,"{&}",$i);print}}' file
```

```
$ cat file
{One day}, {the cat said to the owl}, "{Owl}, {would you like to climb the mountain}?"
{The owl replied}, "{Yes}, {I would}."
{So the cat and owl climbed the mountain}.
{The next day}, {they went to the ocean}.
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/{|}/,"",$0);sub(/[^".?]+/,"{&}",$i);print}}' file
{One day}, the cat said to the owl, "Owl, would you like to climb the mountain?"
One day, {the cat said to the owl}, "Owl, would you like to climb the mountain?"
One day, the cat said to the owl, "{Owl}, would you like to climb the mountain?"
One day, the cat said to the owl, "Owl, {would you like to climb the mountain}?"
{The owl replied}, "Yes, I would."
The owl replied, "{Yes}, I would."
The owl replied, "Yes, {I would}."
{So the cat and owl climbed the mountain}.
{The next day}, they went to the ocean.
The next day, {they went to the ocean}.
```

*Note: You can use `[^[:punct:]]+` instead of `[^".?]+` in the `sub` function to handle other punctuation characters.*